# Design strategy, class relationships

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have an application which has the following structure:

(Removed image, I don't have permission to post images. See here: http://s15.postimg.org/98qc3p7uz/Capture.png)

So 'App' holds Manager instance, Manager holds a vector of 'Connection', each of them holds a Protocol, and each Protocol holds a communication class. All the communication classes reference a single HAL class.

At the moment, the communication class constructor obtains a HAL instance as a singleton, eg. hal = HAL::GetInstance().

To make development and testing easier, I'd like to remove this dependency. Dependency Injection pattern seems ideal for this as it would allow me to use a fake HAL.

However, I don't think the Communication classes should have to do anything with HAL, likewise the protocol classes and the connections.

The main 'App' class DOES have a reference however, but I'm not sure about passing that to Manager->Connections[x]->Protocol->Communication.

Maybe I can abstract it out and let Manager have a reference to the HAL, and then each connection can have a parent pointer to the Manager, but it all seems to be getting messy and overcomplicated just for the sake of providing a HAL class reference to the communication.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: My best advice is: scrap all the classes, and write code that does what you need it to do, and no more. What is the Manager for? How many Protocols are you going to have in a Connections object? Heck, how many Connections are you going to have? Why is Communication an object? What does it do? Most likely, you could eliminate 90% of your code, and have a program that is more readable and more testable. Think about what you want your program to do, not how to abstractly model the entire world.

Comment: The 'Manager' creates the connections. A single connection requires a single protocol (as they may be talking to different devices), and the protocols want to send out packets without worrying about how to send them out, so each protocol requires a communication object. I guess the communication and protocol could be as one.

Comment: And how many connections will your program *have*? How many different protocols? Unless you are trying to build the entire friggin' internet, what purpose does this maze of classes and inheritance and OOP serve?

Comment: Between 64 and 100 connections and 3 different protocols that a connection can use (not changeable once the connection is built). There's only a single HAL, however.

Answer (score 0):

You could let the Manager create instances of `Connection`, `Protocol`, `Communication` and `HAL`. Then the Manager connects all of them. Very simple example in C++:

```
Manager::createEverything()
{
    Connection connection;
    Protocol protocol;
    Communication communication;
    HAL hal;

    communication.setHal(hal);
    protocol.setCommunication(communication);
    connection.setProtocol(protocol);
}
```

You could also use dependency injection for creating different `HAL`-implementations that way. A class design could look like the following:

- [YUML diagram](http://yuml.me/c57ea963)
- [YUML Edit Link](http://yuml.me/edit/c57ea963)

The above is quite simple but should give you an idea. Some more thoughts:

- Use a [Factory](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory) to create the different types of `IHAL`
- Use the [Builder Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder) to do the whole creation and aggregation thing